# Why setting up new galera cluster with mariabackup as sst starts but all other nodes failed with same error?

Tags: clustering, galera, mariadb-10.3, wsrep

I did a fresh reinstallation of mariadb-server on all the nodes
(I removed using `sudo apt purge mariadb-*`)

I started the first node using sudo galera_new_cluster it went fine and is still running. but other nodes threw this error:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.27 database serverLoaded: 
loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; 
enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-12-19 20:23:19 IST; 2min 9s ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
Process: 7089 
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)Process: 7090 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)Process: 7092 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= || VAR=\cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery\; [ $? -eq 0 ] && s`
    Process: 7330 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)Main PID: 7330 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Status: "MariaDB server is down"
    Dec 19 20:22:53 phl-pi-3 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.27 database server...
    Dec 19 20:22:59 phl-pi-3 sh[7092]: WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
    Dec 19 20:22:59 phl-pi-3 mysqld[7330]: 2020-12-19 20:22:59 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log) starting as process 7330 ...
    Dec 19 20:22:59 phl-pi-3 mysqld[7330]: 2020-12-19 20:22:59 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32186)
    Dec 19 20:23:19 phl-pi-3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Dec 19 20:23:19 phl-pi-3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    `Dec 19 20:23:19 phl-pi-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.27 database server.``
```

this is my galera config:

```
[mysqld]#mysql settings
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1
query_cache_size=0query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#galera settings
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.0.15,192.168.0.16,192.168.0.12,10.8.0.6
wsrep_node_address="192.168.0.15"
wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup
wsrep_sst_donor=192.168.0.16
```

all other nodes have same galera config except different wsrep_address and dont have wsrep_sst_donor set.

And the other server config is as below:

```
$ cat 50-server.cnf
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
## See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
## this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]
skip_name_resolve = 1
# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
binlog_format = ROW
innodb_large_prefix=on
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_io_capacity=4000
# * Basic Settings
user = mysqlpid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
# * Fine Tuning
key_buffer_size = 16
Mmax_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections = 100
#table_cache = 64
#thread_concurrency = 10
## * Query Cache Configuration
#query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 64M
## * Logging and Replication
## Error log - should be very few entries.
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
server-id = 16
log_bin = mariadb_bin
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M
#binlog_do_db = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db = exclude_database_name
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
## ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
## Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
# ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
# ssl=on
## * Character sets## MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
tmp_table_size= 64Mmax_heap_table_size= 64M
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

all other nodes have same as above except different server-id

Comment: I realise this is an old question. There is not enough information here, sadly. SystemD is great at hiding relevant info from you. You need to go into the MariaDB error file which by default I think is either either in the datadir (`/var/lib/mysql/`) or in `/var/log/mysql/`. That will show you the real error(s).